# Server 2008 R2 - Change logon behavior to prompt after connecting

Tags: authentication, windows-server-2008-r2

So here's my issue...

I run a set of servers, all running Server 2008 R2. When we're doing maintenance on the server we want to display a message to our users telling them the server is under maintenance rather than just "Remote Logins Disabled".

I found how to set the legal message to display prior to log on, however the problem is that RDP is prompting for credentials before connecting to the server, so the legal message isn't being displayed, and it just takes them straight to "Remote Logins Disabled".

What I'm wondering is, is there a way I can change the default login behavior to take the users to a windows-styled login screen rather than prompting for credentials in the RDP connection window, where the legal notification (aka maintenance notification in this case) will be displayed before they enter their credentials, similar to server 2003's login behavior?